# Identify unique data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am creating a jquery plugin that will sort a list based on data attributes:

```
<ul class="reorder">
  <li data-rating="1" data-category="3">Rating 1 - Category 3</li>
  <li data-rating="5" data-category="1">Rating 5 - Category 1</li>
  <li data-rating="2" data-category="2">Rating 2 - Category 2</li>
  <li data-rating="7" data-category="1">Rating 7 - Category 1</li>
  <li data-rating="21" data-category="3">Rating 21 - Category 3</li>
  <li data-rating="19" data-category="2">Rating 19 - Category 2</li>
</ul>
```

As I don't know how many data attributes will be added, I want to be able to loop through the list and identify unique data attributes (NOT the value of those attributes) to create a set of links:

```
<ul class="reorder-nav">
  <li><a href="#" data-sort="rating">Sort by rating</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-sort="category">Sort by category</a></li>
</ul>
```

My basic idea is to loop through each list item and create an array of data attributes, then filter that array for unique attributes.

I can create an array of all data attributes with `.data()` but other than that I'm a bit stuck so would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to extract the data-x attribute names :

```
var uniqueAttrs = {};
$('.reorder li').each(function(){
   $.each(this.attributes, function(_,a){
     if (a.name.indexOf('data-')===0) {
         uniqueAttrs[a.name.slice(5)] = 1;
     }
   });
});
```

Then you can iterate over the keys of `uniqueAttrs` :

```
for (var attr in uniqueAttrs) {
    console.log(attr); // for example "sort" or "ranking"
}
```

If you can afford to support a limited set of browsers, you can simplify the loop by using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) instead of `attributes`.

Comment: This is a solid solution that answers the question perfectly